# Powershell winform ListView right mouse button context menu binding to specific ListView item

Tags: winforms, powershell, listview, contextmenu, listitem

I'm trying to create clicks for right mouse button which are specific to each item in the listview to be able to execute commands on remote pc. I just don't know how assign the separate context menu to a specific ListViewItem.
I have tried to create form also with an array but I have bumped to the same problem and I don't know how to formulate the problem to search for it on internet.
Thanks for help!
Here is the code:

```
## Set up the environment
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$LastColumnClicked = 0 # tracks the last column number that was clicked
$LastColumnAscending = $false # tracks the direction of the last sort of this column
 
## Create a form and a ListView
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$ListView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
 
## Configure the form
$Form.Text = "Computer List"
 
## Configure the ListView
$ListView.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$ListView.Width = $Form.ClientRectangle.Width
$ListView.Height = $Form.ClientRectangle.Height
$ListView.Anchor = "Top, Left, Right, Bottom"
 
# Add the ListView to the Form
$Form.Controls.Add($ListView)
 
# Add columns to the ListView
$ListView.Columns.Add("Computer Name", -2) | Out-Null
$ListView.Columns.Add(" Test") | Out-Null
 
# Add list items
$contextMenuStrip = [System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip]@{}
$listView.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
##Computer1##
$ListViewItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("computer1")
$click1 = {Invoke-Command -UseSSL -ComputerName computer1 }
$click2 = {Invoke-Command -UseSSL -ComputerName computer1 }
$item1 = $contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Run 1")
$item1.add_Click($click1)
$item2 = $contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Run 2")
$item2.add_Click($click2)
$listView.Add_MouseClick({param($sender,$e)
    if ($e.Button -eq [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right){
        if ($listView.FocusedItem.GetBounds(
            [System.Windows.Forms.ItemBoundsPortion]::Entire).Contains($e.Location)){
            $contextMenuStrip.Show([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position)
        }
    } 
})
$ListView.Items.Add($ListViewItem) | Out-Null

##computer2##
$contextMenuStrip = [System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip]@{}
$ListViewItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("computer2")
$click1 = {Invoke-Command -UseSSL -ComputerName computer2 }
$click2 = {Invoke-Command -UseSSL -ComputerName computer2 }
$item1 = $contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Run 3")
$item1.add_Click($click1)
$item2 = $contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Run 4")
$item2.add_Click($click2)
$listView.Add_MouseClick({param($sender,$e)
    if ($e.Button -eq [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right){
        if ($listView.FocusedItem.GetBounds(
            [System.Windows.Forms.ItemBoundsPortion]::Entire).Contains($e.Location)){
            $contextMenuStrip.Show([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position)
        }
    } 
})
$ListView.Items.Add($ListViewItem) | Out-Null

## Set up the event handler
$ListView.add_ColumnClick({SortListView $_.Column})
 
## Event handler
function SortListView
{
 param([parameter(Position=0)][UInt32]$Column)
 
$Numeric = $true # determine how to sort
 
# if the user clicked the same column that was clicked last time, reverse its sort order. otherwise, reset for normal ascending sort
if($Script:LastColumnClicked -eq $Column)
{
    $Script:LastColumnAscending = -not $Script:LastColumnAscending
}
else
{
    $Script:LastColumnAscending = $true
}
$Script:LastColumnClicked = $Column
$ListItems = @(@(@())) # three-dimensional array; column 1 indexes the other columns, column 2 is the value to be sorted on, and column 3 is the System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem object
 
foreach($ListItem in $ListView.Items)
{
    # if all items are numeric, can use a numeric sort
    if($Numeric -ne $false) # nothing can set this back to true, so don't process unnecessarily
    {
        try
        {
            $Test = [Double]$ListItem.SubItems[[int]$Column].Text
        }
        catch
        {
            $Numeric = $false # a non-numeric item was found, so sort will occur as a string
        }
    }
    $ListItems += ,@($ListItem.SubItems[[int]$Column].Text,$ListItem)
}
 
# create the expression that will be evaluated for sorting
$EvalExpression = {
    if($Numeric)
    { return [Double]$_[0] }
    else
    { return [String]$_[0] }
}
 
# all information is gathered; perform the sort
$ListItems = $ListItems | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression=$EvalExpression; Ascending=$Script:LastColumnAscending}
 
## the list is sorted; display it in the listview
$ListView.BeginUpdate()
$ListView.Items.Clear()
foreach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{
    $ListView.Items.Add($ListItem[1])
}
$ListView.EndUpdate()
}
 
## Show the form
$Response = $Form.ShowDialog()

})
$ListView.Items.Add($ListViewItem) | Out-Null
```

Comment: This is really not a PowerShell code issue,. It's a UX/UI design issue. This lin e[$ListView.Items.Add($ListViewItem) | Out-Null] needs to be above [$Response = $Form.ShowDialog()] or it will error out on form close and this '})' is not matched in what you posted. So, maybe move this to code review and post more of it there. Are you trying to do this without first selecting the element or after selecting it? In normal UX/UI models-design, actions cannot be rendered on a non-selected element. This way you'd use the Selected.

Comment: Also, if you step thru your code a segment at a time, other errors occur that need to be addressed. For example [Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot add or insert the item 'computer2' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its 
current location or clone it.
Parameter name: item"
At line:149 char:1]